# How to get last end of url and use the same end to get an embed content

Tags: php, html, regex

Hi guys this is the problem I am facing.
This is the web address that i have

> http://localhost/movie/mp.php?id=tt2527336

i want to separate only the tt2527336 as a string

then I want to put it back on the tail of URL

like this

> http://localhost/movie/ratings.php?id=tt2527336

So I want to do it with either php or html. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `localhost` is your local server on your PC. We can't access your PC because that's just the alias for your loopback address!

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```
<?php

$input = 'http://localhost/movie/mp.php?id=tt2527336';
$new = 'http://localhost/movie/ratings.php';

$query = parse_url($input);

if (key_exists('query', $query)) {
    $query = '?' . $query['query'];
} else {
    $query = '';
}

$new .= $query;
echo "Output: $new\n";
```

Produces result:

```
Output: http://localhost/movie/ratings.php?id=tt2527336
```

Answer (score 0):

#### With `preg_match_all()`

I guess, maybe

```
id=\K\S+
```

would be somewhat close.

#### Test

```
$re = '/id=\K\S+/s';
$str = 'http://localhost/movie/mp.php?id=tt2527336';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
$output = 'http://localhost/movie/ratings.php?id=' . $matches[0][0];

echo $output;
```

#### Output

```
http://localhost/movie/ratings.php?id=tt2527336
```

---

#### With `preg_replace()`

Or another option is `preg_replace`:

#### Test

```
$re = '/.*id=(\S+)/s';
$str = 'http://localhost/movie/mp.php?id=tt2527336';
$subst = 'http://localhost/movie/ratings.php?id=$1';

echo preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

#### Output

```
http://localhost/movie/ratings.php?id=tt2527336
```

---

If you wish to simplify/update/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/D2jqrc/1/). You can watch the matching steps or modify them in [this debugger link](https://regex101.com/r/D2jqrc/1/debugger), if you'd be interested. The debugger demonstrates that how [a RegEx engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines) might step by step consume some sample input strings and would perform the matching process.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]